# meaning of "didn't appear too thrilled to get the car."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

1) I have learned about "too ~ to" construction.

> "He is too young to travel alone"

This sentence means that he cannot travel alone.

2) Then, what's the meaning of this sentence?

> He didn't appear too thrilled to get the car.

Did he get the car? or not?
or Though he got the car, he wasn't very excited?

3) If the "too ~ to" of the second sentence is different from that of the first sentence, why is it? Why does the rule not apply to the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Too" in this sentence is being used as "very". This is one of the meanings that "too" can have in a sentence, functioning as an adverb. In this sentence, it is clear that the subject of the sentence is not very appreciative of the car - the sentence is also correct without "too", but a little less idiomatic.

Comment: What are you indicating by "this sentence"? You mean "He didn't appear too thrilled to get the car."?

Comment: Yes, the answer refers to sentence (2), the one you were puzzled about. (It mentions 'the car!) He got it but wasn't very excited.

Answer (score 4):

This usage of *too* is an example of [understatement](https://en.wikipedia.org/understatement). It occurs only with verbs in the negative.

> My mother wasn't too pleased about the mess in the kitchen.

Variants with the same meaning are to be "none too pleased" and not to be "any too pleased."